# Is it possible to receive in one field the value of another field generated from a Faker?

Tags: ruby, httparty

```
@@base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
    @@body = 
    {
    "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password": Faker::Number.number(6),
    "password_confirmation": 
     }    
}.to_json
```

I'm trying to pass in the body the value generated by gem faker in the password field to the password_verification field.

Comment: This makes heavy use of class variables which is usually a bad sign. Have you considered using constants instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just determine the value upfront:

```
@@base_url = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
password = Faker::Number.number(6)
@@body = {
  "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password": password,
    "password_confirmation": password
  }    
}.to_json
```

Btw do you really need class variables (starting with `@@`)? I cannot think of many situations in which a class variable is a good approach.

Comment: spickermann
Sorry my friend, I made a little mistake regarding the variables !. Thank you so much for your help!